# Use the `with` django method to produce several aliases

Tags: django

At the beginning I wanted to create an aliases on a variable in a django template with something like `{% loan.customer as customer %}`. Someone explains to me that the best method is to use

```
{% with loan.customer as customer %}
<div> customer </div>
{% endwith %}
```

What do I have to do if I want to make several aliases with this method, e.g., `{% loan.customer as customer %}` and `{% request.user as user %}` become

```
{% with loan.customer as customer request.user as user %}
<div> customer </div>
<div> user </div>
{% endwith %}
```

I think I can't do such thing, but I would like your opinion on the subject.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The current standard syntax is not with the `as` as far as I know, so it might explain why it does not work:

```
{% with customer=loan.customer user=request.user %}
<div>{{ customer }}</div>
<div>{{ user }}</div>
{% endwith %}
```

[See official documentation of the `with` templatetag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#with)